# Storing viewmodel data in Session creates problems with validation using FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, sitecore, fluentvalidation

I'm currently working on a large project involving [Sitecore CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/) (7.2). For viewmodel validation we are using [FluentValidations](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). Because of the combination of Sitecore and FluentValidations I seem to be running in some kind of technical deadlock. I sort-of found a solution myself, but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach or not. Here's the problem:

### Situation

There is a Sitecore component which contains a HTML form. Via the modelbinder each value of this form is binded to it's corresponding field in the (complex) viewmodel. This is standard .NET MVC approach.

However, some values in the viewmodel are NOT part of the form. For instance, a date at which the mutation will be applied is calculated by the application. The user can only see this date-value as plain text, and thus can not edit it. It's still part of the viewmodel though. To make sure this value is being posted back to the model in code, one would normally use a hidden field. But if I use a hidden field, it means that users are able to spoof that date and because some validations depend on this value, they are able to spoof the entire validity of the form.

Moreover, in the same viewmodel I have a list of complex objects that I can't simply put in a hidden field (or I should serialize it to JSON, which I don't want).

The conclusion is that I need to store this data somewhere else. Somewhere the user can't spoof it, but I'm still able to validate user input with FluentValidations. I therefore decided to put the entire viewmodel in the users Session, and delete it directly after a succesful mutation.

### Problem

By using session data I run into problems. Let's first see these steps:

1. (GET) Viewmodel is created. Calculated date is set and list of complex types is retrieved once from a (slow) webservice.
2. Entire viewmodel is stored as session data.
3. Form is shown to the user, who fills the form. Some data is only shown as readonly, like the date and list of complex types.
4. User submits form, FluentValidations kicks in to validate the data (POST).

That's where I run into problems. The validation done by FluentValidations kicks in *before* it reaches the POST controller method. That's exactly the way we want it, because that means validation errors are automatically added to the ModelState. However, because of security reasons I don't want to add this data as hidden fields to the cshtml file, which means they are empty at the time FluentValidations is going to validate the form.

This is creating problems because some of the form validations rely on the missing data. What I basically want is to *merge* the viewmodel that is stored in the session with the viewmodel that was posted to the controller method. But I have to do that before FluentValidations is going to do it's work.

### My current solution

Gladly, I learned about FluentValidation's `IValidatorInterceptor`: an interface that can be used to 'do stuff' before or after the validations process kicks in. I used the `BeforeMvcValidation` method to do my merging process. The code is as follows:

```
public ValidationContext BeforeMvcValidation(ControllerContext controllerContext, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session == null)
            return validationContext;

        var sessionData = controllerContext.HttpContext.Session["some_identifier"];

        if (sessionData == null)
            return validationContext;

        var mergedObjectToValidate = Utils.MergeViewModelData(sessionData, validationContext.InstanceToValidate);

        // Unfortunately, we have to do this..
        var privateSetterProperty = validationContext.GetType().GetProperty(ValidationContextInstancePropertyName);

        if (privateSetterProperty == null)
            return validationContext;

        privateSetterProperty.SetValue(validationContext, mergedObjectToValidate);
        return validationContext;
    }
```

Basically this interceptor method allows me to do my merging-process *before* validation. So I thought I had the solution here, but as you can see I am using reflection to set a property. That is because the property `InstanceToValidate` in the ValidationContext object has a private setter. I simply can not set it without using reflection. Which is, obviously, a bit dirty.

It does work exactly as I want though! :) I do not need any hidden fields that can be spoofed (which is horrible for straight-trough-processing) and I can still use FluentValidations exactly as I always did before. Also, the MVC modelbinding-process is left untouched, which I prefer.

### The actual question

*So the above solution works exactly as you want so what are your questions?!* Well, simple:

1. I'm using reflection to set a private property in a 3rd party library (FluentValidations). The obvious answer is: don't go that way. But in this case it works flawlessly. If the InstanceToValidate-property had a public setter, I wouldn't even be posting this question at all: I would feel like I nailed it. But unfortunately it is private, so are there any real reasons why I shouldn't do this, maybe someone being an expert in FluentValidations behaviour?
2. Let's say there is a genuine reason why I shouldn't go this way; is there another approach which has the same effect? Can I hook in even earlier, so before FluentValidations kicks in, perhaps some kind of 'hook' just after the MVC model-binding process but before validation kicks in?
3. Is this entire approach simply wrong and should I tackle it in a completely different way?

Thanks!